# How to trigger a build for any branch in buildbot

Tags: buildbot

I am using `buildbot` in a project and I have a setup of a scheduler, that automatically builds the project every time when there is a change, to test whether it compiles fine. This works and buildbot detects the changes on all branches but the scheduler always builds the `master` branch, no matter which branch the change is on. I want it to build the branch that the change is on but I have trouble making that work. Here are the relevant parts of the buildbot configuration:

GitPoller:

```
c['change_source'].append(GitPoller(
    repourl='git@git.somewhere.com:someproject.git',
    branches=True,
    pollinterval=60))
```

Scheduler:

```
c['schedulers'].append(AnyBranchScheduler(
    name='all',
    treeStableTimer=2*60,
    builderNames=['builder 1', 'builder 2']))
```

This is a helper function that I use on several builders to checkout the code. I am almost always calling it with no parameters. Using the parameter is a rare case for a specific branch, and the above scheduler does not run such a builder. I assume that when I use no parameters, I am always running in the `else` block:

```
def CheckoutFactory(whichBranch = ''):
    factory = BuildFactory()
    if whichBranch:
        factory.addStep(Git(repourl='git@git.somewhere.com:someproject.git', branch=whichBranch, mode='full', method='fresh', alwaysUseLatest=True, progress=True))
    else:
        factory.addStep(Git(repourl='git@git.somewhere.com:someproject.git', mode='full', method='fresh', alwaysUseLatest=True, progress=True))
    return factory
```

What is wrong here? Am I doing something wrong and how do I make buildbot run the builds on the branches with the changes?

Configuration:

- The buildbot master is running on XUbuntu `16.04.1` 64-bit.
- The buildbot version is `0.8.12`. (from the repos)
- Git is version `2.7.4`. (from the repos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it. It seems that is not as automatic as I had thought. The branch has to be passed to the `Git` step, using the value of the `branch` property. I did it like this:

```
factory.addStep(Git(repourl='git@git.somewhere.com:someproject.git', branch=WithProperties('%s', 'branch'), mode='full', method='fresh', alwaysUseLatest=True, progress=True))
```

The relevant change is that this parameter has been added:

```
branch=WithProperties('%s', 'branch')
```

I am using the deprecated `WithProperties` and not `Propery` because that would trigger [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817917/ubuntu-16-04-lts-buildbot-how-to-fix-dependencies-problem), and I didn't want to change my configuration too much.